# Search and replace two words with ex command

Tags: vim, regular-expression

I want to search and replace 2 words with 2 other words with one `g/.../s/.../.../g` command. For example to replace word 'car' with 'truck' and 'cat' with 'dog' with one ex command in Vim.

Comment: Just to save some time by using one command instead of two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `\=` special replacement which allows to run `vim` code:

For instance, to swap `foo` and `bar`:

```
%s/foo\|bar/\=submatch(0) == "foo" ? "bar" : "foo"/g
```

Or for your example:

```
%s/ca[rt]/\=submatch(0) == "car" ? "truck" : "dog"/g
```

See:

```
:h sub-replace-expression
```

for details.

Answer (score 2):

The [SwapStrings.vim](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/#SWAPSTRINGS) plugin allows to do this elegantly:

```
:%SwapStrings car truck
:%SwapStrings cat dog
```

More alternatives can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578549/easiest-way-to-swap-occurrences-of-two-strings-in-vim).

Answer (score 0):

```
:%s/foo/bar/gc
```

This command changes foo with bar!

:%s is a substitute for vim

Comment: I knew it. But my aim is, for example, to change "foo" with "bar" and "abc" with "def" using only one command, not two.

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple commands in a row using `|`, as a command delimiter.

```
%s/cat/dog/g|%s/car/truck/g
```